# How to push (append) a list in Firebase Realtime Database from Unity, C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

So, I want to store the inventory of the player in Firebase Realtime Database.
I set up a basic schema, and I want to add the items (their names, actually) under the inventory "branch".
I am trying to do it with the push method, but it ain't working for me right now.

I got the following script which updates the player's inventory client-side and should update the database to, with appending the inventory "branch".

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void pickUp() {
        Transform free_place = findFirstFreePlace();
        if(free_place) {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
                if (free_place.name.Contains(i.ToString())) {
                    items[i] = currentPickable;
                    reference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("inventory").Child(items[i].item_name).Push();
                    lastIndex = i;
                }
            }
            free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = items[lastIndex].item_pic;
            free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there's slight confusion around what `Push()` does in this context. If you read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#saving_data), it says:

> Add to a list of data. Every time you call Push(), Firebase generates a unique key that can also be used as a unique identifier, such as `user-scores/<user-id>/<unique-score-id>`.

Basically, it's giving you a place you can safely write into rather than actually adding something to the Database. You should check out the [sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#update_specific_fields), but I think I can illustrate both what you intend to do and a cool way to use `Push()` for your use case.

```
public async void pickUp() {
    Transform free_place = findFirstFreePlace();
    if(free_place) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        var elements = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
            if (free_place.name.Contains(i.ToString())) {
                items[i] = currentPickable;
                elements.Add(items[i].item_name);
                lastIndex = i;
            }
        }
        await reference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("inventory").SetValueAsync(itemNames);
        free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = items[lastIndex].item_pic;
        free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
        free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
        free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is that I build a list of the items before hand. Then I set the inventory entry to this list. If I depended on the previous state, I'd probably prefer to do this as a transaction instead.

I also use async/await. I'm not sure how important it is that this logic runs before you update your game's UI, but setting anything in Firebase is an asynchronous operation (it runs in the background). You can omit this if it's not important that you stay in sync.

If you wanted to have uniquely identified weapon slots. You could instead do something like:

```
var childReference = reference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("inventory");
var key = childReference.Key;

// ... more logic here ...

childReference.Child(key).SetValueAsync(item_name);
```

A few more hints:

- I'd recommend that you use the [ValueChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#value-events) listener whenever possible to keep your game state in sync with your server state. Realtime Database will always be running asynchronously in the background, and this way you can help stay up to date as more data becomes available.
- If asynchronous programming in Unity is new to you, check out [my post on the subject](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html).

Comment: It confuses me a bit. The `=>` part gives me the following error: `Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<Item, int, bool>'`

Comment: I forgot to add a `return`. Sorry about that, as I said I did it from memory :-/

Comment: After running the game, it gives me the following error: `ArgumentException: Invalid type System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[Item,System.String] for conversion to Variant`

Comment: I realize that the where comment is wrong anyway. Give me a moment.

Comment: Even if I messed up the exact syntax, I think that's more readable.

Comment: It's still not adding items to the database. You wrote itemNames in the function, what did u want to write there? With items, it's still not working.

Comment: I assumed that that's what you'd wanted in your database (could easily be IDs, or you could reformat for key:<item_id>, value:<count>. Do you see any errors?

The key is SetValueAsync().

Comment: Now it's setting the inventory's value to itemNames. I would like to append that list with the item names which are currently in the player's inventory.

Comment: The most important part is that you have stuff syncing up. Hopefully you can tweak the rest to suit your game's design needs. If you're asking in particular how you synchronously update the list to avoid losing data &c, you will want to look into Transactions. In the transaction callback, you will get a mutable state that you can safely mutate. But your callback will run multiple times as data resolves itself. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've finally figured it out.
With the help of `Push()` method's unique id generation, I am able to add childs with the same item name to the inventory node.
Firstly, I create that unique id, then,  I add that unique id to the database and set it's value to the item name.

Edit: I mixed my original solution with Pux0r3's solution, so that it uses async/await.

```
public async void pickUp() {
    Transform free_place = findFirstFreePlace();
    if (free_place) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        var elements = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
            if (free_place.name.Contains(i.ToString())) {
                items[i] = currentPickable;
                elements.Add(items[i].item_name);
                lastIndex = i;
            }
        }
        string key = reference.Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("inventory").Push().Key;
        await reference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("inventory").Child(key).SetValueAsync(currentPickable.item_name);
        free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = items[lastIndex].item_pic;
        free_place.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
        free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
        free_place.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
    }
}
```